# Máscara para um campo datepicker em uma aplicação

Tags: c#, wpf

Possuo uma aplicação em wpf, assim existem janelas que têm campos para tipos data, coloquei esses campos com datepicker em que há um calendário para a escolha da data.

Até ai tudo bem, o que não consegui por é uma máscara para ficar assim "00/00/0000" nesse campo, aceitando somente números.

Alguém tem alguma ideia do que posso fazer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Start, StringFormat=d}" />
```

ou

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=OrderDate, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"/>
```

Comment: <DatePicker Name="datepickerData" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
      Margin="421,128,0,0"
      VerticalAlignment="Top"
      Height="31" Width="128" MouseLeftButtonDown="datepickerData_MouseLeftButtonDown"/> eu tenho isso Fabio, coloco ai dentro?

Comment: <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                DisplayDate="{x:Static System:DateTime.Now}"
                SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Data, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}"
                Margin="139,58,0,0" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="120"/>

Comment: Tenta isso acima, estou fora do meu pc com windows... mas isso deve servir.

Comment: Error 1 Unknown build error, 'Key cannot be null.
Parameter name: key Line 114 Position 88.'  da um erro asim. Não aceita x: Static System:DateTime.Now

Comment: Desculpe, cometi um erro, a propriedade que vc tem de aplicar a mascara, é a DisplayDate, não selectedDate <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" DisplayDate="{Binding PROPRIEDADE_DATA, StringFormat='{}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}'}" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Data}" Margin="139,58,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"

Comment: PROPRIEDADE_DATA o que seria?

Comment: A sua propriedade que estará selecionada. Por exemplo, no seu modelo de dados, a você tem algo do tipo DataSelecionada... Então você colocaria isso